# Как получить значение одного поля из POST?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Мне нужно получить только id для поста, создавать pojo с одним филдом как-то не хочется. А как еще это можно сделать для получение информации через post метод?

Думал еще сделать example/{id} хоть это и протеворечит паттернам ссылок для rest, что я видел.

Comment: Напишите, что должна делать операция и что означает ее параметр.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ваш запрос ничего не изменяет в системе, а служит только для получения каких-то данных, то необходимо использовать GET-запросы.

В таком случае указывать ID в урле считается нормой.

Но если ваш метод предназначен только для текущего пользователя и вы хотите пробрасывать его в урле, то это будет плохой затеей. В таком случае лучше вытаскивать ID пользователя из токена авторизации, с которым пришел запрос от пользователя.